# Is PM2 meant to be used during development process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, nodemon

I'm starting with Node.js world and I noticed that node process doesn't restart automatically.

Searching around I found that nodemon can do that work but I also found that PM2 is an alternative to nodemon. So should I try PM2 for development or just leave it for production and use nodemon for development (which seems very easy to setup)?

Comment: IMO, Nodemon works fine for development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A node process should *not* restart unless told to do so. You can use PM2 for development with the `watch` feature - similar results to `nodemon`. I recommend PM2 if you want to pass in a bunch of environment variables from your PM2 `ecosystem.config.js` file. Otherwise, I’d use `nodemon` as [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx) said.

Answer (score 3):

I will just add that there is pm2-dev utility http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-development/ as well.