# How to include nodemon in pm2

Tags: package.json, pm2

I am using pm2 for my application, I need to have a fast refresh, we can achieve this with nodemon. But when I tried to pass inside the node_args I am not able to get.

**Approach 1**

```
node_args: ["--inspect", "nodemon"]
```

**Error**

```
Can't find module nodemon
```

**Tried Solution**

1. Installed nodemon as globally
2. Installed nodemon as devDependencies

**Approach 2**

```
node_args: ["--inspect", "--nodemon"]
```

**Error**

```
node: bad option: --nodemon
```

process.json

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app_local",
      "script": "dist/src/app.js",
      "watch": "dist/src/**/*.js",
      "error_file": "logs/error.log",
      "out_file": "logs/app.log",
      "merge_logs": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "1G",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "instances": "1",
      "min_uptime": "2s",
      "node_args": ["--inspect", "--nodemon"],
      "env": { "NODE_ENV": "development", "PORT": "4000" }
    },
    {
      "name": "app_staging_cluster",
      "script": "dist/src/app.js",
      "watch": "dist/src/**/*.js",
      "error_file": "logs/error.log",
      "out_file": "logs/app.log",
      "merge_logs": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "1G",
      "exec_mode": "cluster",
      "instances": "4",
      "min_uptime": "2s",
      "env": { "NODE_ENV": "development", "PORT": "3000" }
    },
    {
      "name": "app_prod",
      "script": "dist/src/app.js",
      "watch": "dist/src/app.js",
      "error_file": "NULL",
      "out_file": "NULL",
      "merge_logs": true,
      "max_memory_restart": "1G",
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "instances": "1",
      "min_uptime": "2s",
      "env": { "NODE_ENV": "production", "PORT": "8080" }
    }
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=development gulp build && pm2 start process.json --only app_local --no-daemon",
```

Even added the watch flag in process.json but not working. anything to updated in the json file.

That's why thought of using nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

as stated here, I don't think you really need nodemon AND pm2... I use pm2 for personal projects in 'production' but nodemon when developing locally...

Hope this answer helps guide you further!
[Is PM2 meant to be used during development process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918704/is-pm2-meant-to-be-used-during-development-process)